# Relationship links in JSON to parent don't link back up one level, possibly due to two keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jackson, json-api, crnk

I have a "Movie" class and a "Actor" class. I have mapped these in the entities as a OneToMany and vice versa (one Movie can have many Actors). Crnk is creating the endpoints and they are working nicely, apart from the link under "relationships" on the "Actor" creates a URL that is under "Actor" endpoint when it really should go back to the root Movie URL.

So under the Actors findAll `relationships.movie.links.related` should be:
`"related": "/api/v1/movies/1"`
instead of
`"related": "/api/v1/actors/156/movie"`
and similarly for `self`

**Movie findAll endpoint**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "v1/movies",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "I.M.Movie"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "actors": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/v1/movies/1/relationships/actors",
                        "related": "/api/v1/movies/1/actors"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/api/v1/movies/1"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "totalResourceCount": null
    }
}
```

**Actor findAll endpoint**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "156",
            "type": "v1/actors",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "I.R.Actor"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "movie": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/api/v1/actors/156/relationships/movies",
                        "related": "/api/v1/actors/156/movies"
                    }
                },
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "/api/v1/actors/156"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "totalResourceCount": null
    }
}
```

Here are the entities and their relationship annotations:

**MovieEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "movie")
@JsonApiResource(type = "v1/movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity implements BaseEntity<String> {

    @Id
    @JsonApiId
    @Column(name="MID")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String secondId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonApiRelation
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ActorEntity> actors;
}
```

**ActorEntity**

```
@Entity(name = "SP")
@JsonApiResource(type = "v1/actors")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ActorEntity implements BaseEntity<String> {
    @Id
    @JsonApiId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MOVIEID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @JsonApiRelation(serialize = SerializeType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private MovieEntity movie;
}
```

You'll notice also that Movie has two ID's, it has it's main primary key using column `MID`, but the column used as the foreign key is `ID` which is also a unique ID. This is unfortunately the set up of the database and cannot be changed. Also, as far as I can tell, using `referencedColumnName` should get around this issue.

If anyone has any suggestions on why this might not be working in it's current state it would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

p.s I changed the class names for paranoia reasons, just in case I missed something and a variable somewhere doesn't quite line up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far referencedColumnName annotation attribute is not supported. But it would be thinkable to introduce support for the in the JpaRelationshipRepository implementation. Currently it is strictly primary key based.